# Angular get content inside component balises

Tags: angular, typescript, components, parent-child

I'm searching how to get the content inside my component call.
Is there a way to get it?

```
<my-component>get what is here inside in my-component</my-component>
```

---

```
<my-select [list]="LMObjects" [multiple]="true">{{MyObject.MyName}}</my-select>
```

and it would generate

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select  multiple="@InputMultiple">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let obj of ListObj" [value]="obj.id">
        {{@InputChildBlock}} // copy of block inside balises
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you should have a look at `content projection`: https://angular.io/guide/content-projection

Comment: @GunnarB. Not it's not helping me because I thing before giving it to child html, the TS will try to interpret it already

Answer (score 0):

**you can do this in your-component html:**

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

**and if you need pass multiple html tags you can do it:**

in the component html file:

```
<ng-content select="p"></ng-content> 
<ng-content select="div"></ng-content>
```

in place where you will your component:

```
<my-component>
  <p> lorem ipusm text </p>
  <div> basic div </div>
</my-component>
```

Comment: it's not realy what I search to do :/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a parent component which uses a child component and want to pass in something, e.g. text or another component, that should be displayed inside the child component, then `content-projection` is what you need.

parent html

```html
<p>I'm the parent. Look at my child here:</p>
<my-child>I'm the child :)</my-child>
```

child html

```html
<ng-content></ng-content><br />
Nice to meet you!
```

Resulting DOM:

```html
<p>I'm the parent. Look at my child here:</p>
<my-child>
  I'm the child :)
  Nice to meet you!
</my-child>
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please specify more.